# iOS App Upload size limit on cellular data

Tags: ios, iphone

I have developed an app that will upload a file to a server. Is there a limit on size uploading file using the cellular provider data. I think Wifi has no limit, but how about the cellular provider data, does OS limit the size of using data? If so, what is the size limit?

Comment: `Is there a limit on size uploading file over ... cellular data?` What do you mean? Limit with your cellular provider? Or a limit in the OS? Your original question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: It means the cellular provider data

Comment: Why are you asking on SO, then? That's a question for the provider.

Comment: I thought this site is open for dev like me, which is asking for the help of other tech people.

Comment: I have the same question. No idea why this is getting downvoted so much. From what I can tell it can vary between carrier and what settings they have on their account. I do a POST request in iOS that is 100MB plus with no problem. I do have a user on a cell data plan that has his POST command truncated which ends up giving us an 500.0 error. I believe it is carrier induced but I don't have proof yet.

Answer (score -1):

Your app will have no problem continuing to spray HTTP Post requests all over the internets as often as you tell it to, or whatever other exotic web magic you're invoking.

If you are referring to particular upload limits of individual cell phone data plans, then I think you'll have to read the fine print of every different contract with every different mobile provider to get an answer, and that answer will be "it varies"

Of course, if you are considering sending particularly large data-sets back to a server, you're probably going to consider breaking it into small pieces and handling dropped packets gracefully anyway, so I'm assuming you're not asking "what's the biggest file I can push through completely intact".

Comment: I see, but what if completely intact?